# Concatenate column values in a pandas DataFrame while ignoring NaNs

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a the following pandas table

df:

```
 EVNT_ID col1 col2 col3 col4
 123454   1    Nan   4    5
 628392   Nan   3   Nan   7
 293899   2    Nan  Nan   6
 127820   9    11    12   19
```

Now I am trying to concat all the columns except the first column and I want my data frame to look in the following way

new_df:

```
 EVNT_ID col1 col2 col3 col4 new_col
 123454   1    Nan   4    5   1|4|5
 628392   Nan   3   Nan   7    3|7
 293899   2    Nan  Nan   6    2|6
 127820   9    11    12   19  9|11|12|19
```

I am using the following code

```
df['new_column'] = df[~df.EVNT_ID].apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x.dropna().astype(str).values), axis=1)
```

but it is giving me the following error

`ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

I would really appreciate if any one can give me where I am wrong. I'd really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `filter` and `agg`:

```
df.filter(like='col').agg(
    lambda x: x.dropna().astype(int).astype(str).str.cat(sep='|'), axis=1)

0         1|4|5
1           3|7
2           2|6
3    9|11|12|19
dtype: object
```

Or,

```
df.drop('EVNT_ID', 1).agg(
        lambda x: x.dropna().astype(int).astype(str).str.cat(sep='|'), axis=1)

0         1|4|5
1           3|7
2           2|6
3    9|11|12|19
dtype: object
```

---

If performance is important, you can use a list comprehension:

```
joined = [
    '|'.join([str(int(x)) for x in r if pd.notna(x)]) 
    for r in df.iloc[:,1:].values.tolist()
]
joined
# ['1|4|5', '3|7', '2|6', '9|11|12|19']

df.assign(new_col=joined)   

   EVNT_ID  col1  col2  col3  col4     new_col
0   123454   1.0   NaN   4.0     5       1|4|5
1   628392   NaN   3.0   NaN     7         3|7
2   293899   2.0   NaN   NaN     6         2|6
3   127820   9.0  11.0  12.0    19  9|11|12|19
```

If you can forgive the overhead of assignment to a DataFrame, here's timings for the two fastest solutions here.

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

# In this post.
%%timeit
[
     '|'.join([str(int(x)) for x in r if pd.notna(x)]) 
     for r in df.iloc[:,1:].values.tolist()
]
# RafaelC's answer.
%%timeit
[
    '|'.join([k for k in a if k])
    for a in zip(*df.fillna('').astype(str).iloc[:, 1:].values.tolist())
]    

31.9 ms ± 800 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
23.7 ms ± 409 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Although note the answers aren't identical because @RafaelC's code produces floats: `['1.0|2.0|9.0', '3.0|11.0', ...]`. If this is fine, then great. Otherwise you'll need to convert to int which adds more overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
df['new_col'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x:
    '|'.join(str(el) for el in x if str(el) != 'nan'), axis=1)
```

Initially I thought about `x.dropna()` instead of `x if str(el) != 'nan'`,
but `%timeit` showed that `dropna()` works much slower.

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension and `zip`

```
>>> [['|'.join([k for k in a if k])] for a in zip(*df.fillna('').astype(str).iloc[:, 1:].values)]
```

Timing seems alright

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000)

%timeit [['|'.join([k for k in a if k])] for a in zip(*df.fillna('').astype(str).iloc[:, 1:].values)]
10.8 ms ± 568 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.filter(like='col').agg(lambda x: x.dropna().astype(int).astype(str).str.cat(sep='|'), axis=1)
1.68 s ± 91.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: '|'.join(str(el) for el in x if str(el) != 'nan'), axis=1)
87.8 ms ± 5.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df.assign(new_col=['|'.join([str(int(x)) for x in r if ~np.isnan(x)]) for r in df.iloc[:,1:].values])
45.1 ms ± 1.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for the timings! Although it isn't a particularly fair comparison unless the first list comp is also being assigned, because that incurs overhead.

Comment: That's true, but probably won't add that much overhead ;)

Comment: It is enough to make a difference! I've mirrored your timings in my answer too.

Comment: Yep. saw that. Thanks for the inputs ! :}

Comment: Also our answers aren't identical. Your code produces floats: `['1.0|2.0|9.0', '3.0|11.0', '4.0|12.0', '5|7|6|19']`

Comment: @coldspeed I see, gotta `str(int(float(k)))` or something in the loop ! We'll have similar time I believe :

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import timeit
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date' : ['05/9/2023', '07/10/2023', '08/11/2023', '06/12/2023'],
    'A' : [1,  np.nan,4, 7],
    'B' : [2, np.nan, 5, 8],
    'C' : [3, 6, 9, np.nan]
}).set_index('date')

print(df)

print('.........')

start_time = datetime.now()
df['ColumnA'] = df[df.columns].agg(
    lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),
    axis=1
)
print(df['ColumnA'])

end_time = datetime.now()
print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))


"""
              A    B    C
date                     
05/9/2023   1.0  2.0  3.0
07/10/2023  NaN  NaN  6.0
08/11/2023  4.0  5.0  9.0
06/12/2023  7.0  8.0  NaN
...........................
OUTPUT:

date
05/9/2023     1.0,2.0,3.0
07/10/2023            6.0
08/11/2023    4.0,5.0,9.0
06/12/2023        7.0,8.0
Name: ColumnA, dtype: object
Duration: 0:00:00.002998

"""
```